# get the value of text area by GetElementByName

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to add the value of a textarea to the state of my component. but it doesn't seem to be working. in console.log . it gives me the id correctly but the value as undefined .
the addListItem is triggered by a button.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "../../styles/styles.css";

class BlockInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ id: 0, value: "" }],
  };

  addListItem = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("seed").innerHTML);

    const newItem = {
      id: x,
      value: document.getElementsByName("hi").text,
    };

    document.getElementById("seed").innerHTML = x + 1;
    this.setState({
      items: [...this.state.items, newItem],
    });
  };

  createList = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return items.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <textarea className="item" id={item.id} type="text" name="hi" ></textarea>
          <button type="button" onClick={(e) => this.handleDelete(item)}>
            delete
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

Comment: Separate to the actual question, but rather than querying/mutating the DOM directly, the idiomatic to work with form elements in React is to make them into [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and persist their value to state. You can then read and update its value much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getElementsByName` return an "collection of all elements in the document with the specified name" and not a single one, second you should use value to read what inside the textarea
if you have only one textarea with that name (in your page), this code will work.

```
document.getElementsByName("hi")[0].value
```

Comment: this code creates new textarea everytime i press a button. so the page crashed when i tried that

Comment: you should check if it exist (since your are accessing element [0])
try to add if(document.getElementsByName("hi") && document.getElementsByName("hi")[0])  value = document.getElementsByName("hi")[0].value

Comment: can you console.log(document.getElementsByName("hi").length)  it should return 1 (the number of textarea with that name)

Comment: but there is a new prob;em now whenever I add a textarea it takes only the value of the first one

Comment: yes as it is mentioned in the response, it will take only the first one

Comment: can you explain, what tis the purpose of the app, or mybe you can share a screenshot, so I can advice you on a better solution

Comment: Thanks a lot really your response helped me a lot. I fixed the last problem by defining the index by a variable.